# React Native, Unexpected token (10:6)

Tags: android, react-native

I'm learning React Native, in my example I'm getting the next error:

> Unexpected token (10:6) at Hello.js

The code of my class Hello is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return {
           <View>
               <Text>Hola desde Hello.js</Text>
          </View>
        }
    }
}
```

The Line 10 is ***< View >*** so I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return uses parenthesis, so return (..);

Comment: Oh men!! That was it, thks and sorry :)